# Recaptcha stoken generation (convert from Java to Ruby)

Tags: java, ruby, recaptcha, public-key-encryption

Google have provided the following example code showing how to generate a secure token for their second version of Recaptcha:

```
public class STokenUtils {
  private static final String CIPHER_INSTANCE_NAME = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

  public static final String createSToken(String siteSecret) {
    String sessionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String jsonToken = createJsonToken(sessionId);
    return encryptAes(jsonToken, siteSecret);
  }

  private static final String createJsonToken(String sessionId) {
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    obj.addProperty("session_id", sessionId);
    obj.addProperty("ts_ms", System.currentTimeMillis());
    return new Gson().toJson(obj);
  }

  private static String encryptAes(String input, String siteSecret) {
    try {
      SecretKeySpec secretKey = getKey(siteSecret);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_INSTANCE_NAME);
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
      return BaseEncoding.base64Url().omitPadding().encode(cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private static String decryptAes(String input, String key) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = getKey(key);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_INSTANCE_NAME);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(
        BaseEncoding.base64Url().omitPadding().decode(input)), "UTF-8");
  }

  private static SecretKeySpec getKey(String siteSecret){
    try {
      byte[] key = siteSecret.getBytes("UTF-8");
      key = Arrays.copyOf(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA").digest(key), 16);
      return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

The full code can be found at: https://github.com/google/recaptcha-java

I'm wanting to generate this token in Ruby 2.1+ and have got this far but it outputs incorrect data. I'm trying to slowly debug it, but in the meantime I'm wondering if anyone can see any obvious flaws in my process?

```
      stoken_json = hash_to_json({'session_id' => SecureRandom.uuid, 'ts_ms' => Time.now.to_i})
      cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(:ECB)
      private_key_digest = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(private_key)[0...16]    

      cipher.encrypt
      cipher.key = private_key_digest
      encrypted_stoken = cipher.update(stoken_json) << cipher.final
      encoded_stoken = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(encrypted_stoken).gsub(/\=+\Z/, '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was close. I needed to `digest` not `hexdigest` the private key:

```
private_key_digest = Digest::SHA1.digest(private_key)[0...16]
```

So the final code is:

```
stoken_json = hash_to_json({'session_id' => SecureRandom.uuid, 'ts_ms' => (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i})
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(:ECB)
private_key_digest = Digest::SHA1.digest(private_key)[0...16]

cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = private_key_digest
encrypted_stoken = cipher.update(stoken_json) << cipher.final
encoded_stoken = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(encrypted_stoken).gsub(/\=+\Z/, '')
```

There didn't seem to be a built-in way to strip the padding from the base64 string, thus the `.gsub` at the end.

I also needed the timestamp in milliseconds so that part has been modified too.

In the [recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/) gem there is a method `hash_to_json` that I'm using, otherwise I suspect you'd use the JSON gem.

Comment: does private_key mean site_secret ?

Could you please provide a complete example including view and controller code

Comment: Hi there, the `private_key` is the key from google that they give you. I can't remember the terminology off the top of my head. This solution has been implemented in the recaptcha gem, so take a look at that for implementation guidelines. This answer here answers the question that was how to implement the java code in ruby.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement that without `recaptcha` gem